# Could you explain "We are in the middle of the freeway"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Passage :

> W: I need to check my messages.
>
> M: How are you going to do that? We are in the middle of the freeway!
>
> W: I’m going to use my cell phone. Haven’t you ever done that?
>
> M: No. I just use my cell phone to talk to other people.

Could you explain "We are in the middle of the freeway"?

Comment: Did you look up *freeway* in the dictionary? What did you find?

Comment: I thought it 's an idiom

Comment: But you need to understand the individual words before you know whether they're being used literally or idiomatically, no?

Comment: A controlled-access highway is a type of highway which has been designed for high-speed vehicular traffic, with all traffic flow and ingress/egress regulated. Common English terms are freeway and motorway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In the middle of the freeway* means on the road, far away from a classical computer or internet access - something like this:

[image: image from wikipedia]
<sup>Source: Original uploader was Richmeister at [en.wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeways_in_Australia)</sup>

Comment: I disagree.  There is no implication of being far away from a mobile tower providing internet access. It means "in the midst of highway traffic".  The potential context: the rising number of roadway accidents resulting in death because people are texting or checking email while driving.

Comment: http://oaklandnorth.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/TRAFFIC_grennan_102720092.jpg

Comment: http://97x.com/drunk-woman-leaves-her-car-in-the-middle-of-the-highway-causing-people-to-swerve-at-the-last-minute/v

Comment: http://fox13now.com/2015/03/29/alleged-dui-driver-passes-out-in-middle-of-freeway-dramatic-rescue-caught-on-camera/

Comment: @TRomano but this is a old passage about SMS ( short massages ) on celephone

Comment: @Mohammad:  "In the middle of the freeway" means "on the (busy) highway".